How to seperate dns records to be applied for different purposes?
I have a server that I want to use it for my private e-mail service, and as a web server. I'm using Windows Server 2012 R2 and using mailenable for e-mail service, and apache lounge for just web things. And to make connection between my domain and server, I'm using cloudflare. I set the required dns records but there is something went wrong. While trying to set the records for web serving as proxied, I cannot make the settings compatible for e-mail server as well because of proxy. I don't know what to do, please help? And in the screenshot, I marked the records added for web serving. As you might think, you can see that the second record from the top is linked with first one.just the screenshot
Tried to make every records as proxied but as it needed, it didn't helped.

Stack Overflow is for programming questions only. You might be able to ask on [sf] instead. Otherwise, maybe [su].
